# Tomcat always loads conf/logging.properties ignoring log4j file

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I have a problem with one of my tomcat installations.

The webapp do not pick up a specific log4j.properties file. The only way to make this work was by delete the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties file and adding my log4j.properties file in $CATALINA_BASE/lib/ folder.

I was wondering how to configure it to pick up my webapp specific property file (preferably without deleting conf/logging.properties).

I have tried putting the log4j.properties file in WEB-INF/lib, WEB-INF/classes and in a jar to be picked up but to no avail. The only thing that worked was what I described earlier.

Tomcat version is 6.0.18

The properties file is correct as it is working as described

Comment: The [changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/changelog.html) shows a number of logging related bug-fixes (I searched on "logging" and "log4j"). Maybe a recent Tomcat version does work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Tomcat 6 docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j), put log4j.jar and log4j.properties into WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/classes of your web application.

If that doesn't resolve the issue, please edit your question and include a copy of your log4j.properties file.